# How do I access member function using constant vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am making a program in which I am storing class object in a vector and passing this vector to a friend function as const vector as reference variable and iterating it using const_vector, and I am trying to call member function of the class object using const_iterator so, I am getting error.But when I am doing this without const vector and iterating it without const_iterator then my program is running successfully.Is we can not iterate const_vector or we can not access member variable or function using const_vector.

```
 vector<AccountHolder>::iterator searchAccount(const vector<AccountHolder>& v,long int accno)
{
    vector<AccountHolder>::const_iterator itr;
    for(itr = v.begin();itr!=v.end();itr++)
    {
        if(itr->getAccNo() == accno)return itr;
    }
    return v.end();
}
```

and this is the whole code.

```
 #include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Account{
private:
    long int AccNo;
    char AccType;
public:
    long int getAccNo()
    {
        return AccNo;
    }
    char getAccType()
    {
        return AccType;
    }
    void setAccNo(long int accno)
    {
        AccNo = accno;
    }
    void setAccType(char acctype)
    {
        AccType = acctype;
    }
};

class AccountHolder:public Account{
private:
    string Name;
public:
    string getAccHolderName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    void setAccHolderInfo(long int accno,char acctype,string name)
    {
        setAccNo(accno);
        setAccType(acctype);
        Name = name;
    }
    void displayAccountHolderInfo()
    {
       cout << "Name              : " << getAccHolderName() << endl;
       cout << "Account Number    : " << getAccNo() << endl;
       cout << "Account Type      : " << getAccType() << endl;
    }
    friend void displayAllAccountHolder(vector<AccountHolder> &v);
    friend vector<AccountHolder>::iterator searchAccount(vector<AccountHolder> &v,long int accno);
    //friend bool searchAccount(const vector<AccountHolder> &v,long int accno,char acctype);
    //friend vector<AccountHolder>::iterator searchAccount(const vector<AccountHolder> &v,long int accno=0,string name);
};

void displayAllAccountHolder(vector<AccountHolder> &v)
{
    for(vector<AccountHolder>::iterator itr = v.begin();itr != v.end() ; itr++)
        itr->displayAccountHolderInfo();
}

vector<AccountHolder>::iterator searchAccount(const vector<AccountHolder>& v,long int accno)
{
    vector<AccountHolder>::const_iterator itr;
    for(itr = v.begin();itr!=v.end();itr++)
    {
        if(itr->getAccNo() == accno)return itr;
    }
    return v.end();
}

int main()
{
    vector<AccountHolder> Acc;
    vector<AccountHolder> SavingAcc;
    vector<AccountHolder> CurrentAcc;
    vector<AccountHolder>::iterator temp;
    AccountHolder AccH;
    long int accno;
    char acctype;
    string name;
    do{
        cout << "Select Your Choice : " << endl;
        cout << "1. Insert Data " << endl;
        cout << "2. Display Data " << endl;
        cout << "3. Display All User Data " << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit " << endl;
        cout << "   Enter Your Choice : ";
        int choice;
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: cout << "\nEnter Name : ";
                    cin.get();
                    getline(cin >> ws,name);
                    accNo:
                    cout << "\nEnter Account Number : ";
                    cin >> accno;
                    if(searchAccount(Acc,accno)!=Acc.end())
                    {
                        cout << "\nAccount Number already exist." << endl;
                        goto accNo;
                    }
                    accType:
                    cout << "\nEnter Account Type   : ";
                    cin >> acctype;
                    if(acctype == 's' || acctype =='S')
                    {
                        AccH.setAccHolderInfo(accno,'S',name);
                        SavingAcc.push_back(AccH);
                        Acc.push_back(AccH);
                    }
                    else if(acctype == 'c' || acctype == 'C')
                    {
                        AccH.setAccHolderInfo(accno,'C',name);
                        CurrentAcc.push_back(AccH);
                        Acc.push_back(AccH);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       cout << "\n Invalid Account Type" << endl;
                       goto accType;
                    }
            break;
            case 2: cout << "\nEnter Account Number : ";
                    cin >> accno;
                    cout << "\nEnter Account Type(or just type 'n')  : ";
                    cin.get();
                    cin >> acctype;
                    if(acctype == 's' || acctype == 'S')
                        temp = searchAccount(SavingAcc,accno);
                    else if(acctype == 'c' || acctype == 'C')
                        temp = searchAccount(CurrentAcc,accno);
                    else
                        temp = searchAccount(Acc,accno);
                    if(temp!=SavingAcc.end() && temp!=CurrentAcc.end() && temp!=Acc.end()  )
                        temp->displayAccountHolderInfo();
                    else
                        cout << "\n Account does not exist. " << endl;
            break;
            case 3:displayAllAccountHolder(Acc);
            break;
            case 4: return 0;
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }while(true);
    return 0;
}
```

but when you remove const vector to vector it will work.

vector::iterator searchAccount(const vector& v,long int accno)

Comment: Is the member function marked `const`?

Comment: Please provide code samples (not descriptions of code), and copy-paste the error message (it should explain the issue with your code).

Comment: As others have said, we cannot help you unless you provide us with your code. Please edit your post to include your code, and we'll go from there.

Comment: vector<AccountHolder>::iterator searchAccount(const vector<AccountHolder>& v,long int accno)
{
    vector<AccountHolder>::const_iterator itr;
    for(itr = v.begin();itr!=v.end();itr++)
    {
        if(itr->getAccNo() == accno)return itr;
    }
    return v.end();
}

Comment: Place it in the original post please. Paste it, select it all then press Ctrl + K to format it.

Comment: five bucks says `getAccNo` needs to be changed to `long int getAccNo() const`. You will also have a problem because you are trying to return a `vector<AccountHolder>::const_iterator` as a `vector<AccountHolder>::iterator`. They are different types.

Comment: Sorry, for inconvenience first time I am posting anything here.

Comment: Most of the time, and this is one of those times, you need to provide an [mcve] to be taken seriously when asking a "What's wrong with my code?" question. Example: http://ideone.com/9yoUnX

Comment: please could you explain me what this error is saying "prog.cpp:18:27: error: passing ‘const AccountHolder’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]".

Comment: Every method has a hidden `this` parameter that is a pointer to the class's type.  In this case you are trying to call a method that requires a `AccountHolder * this` and provide a `const AccountHolder * this`. The error message is complaining about the pointer being de-`const`ified, and this is illegal. The solution is down in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem 1:

In order to invoke a method on a constant object, the method must be declared `const` (to declare that the hidden `this` parameter is `const`) and must not attempt to modify the object (because `this` is `const`). Simply not modifying the object inside the method isn't good enough. So

```
long int getAccNo()
{
    return AccNo;
}
```

must be

```
long int getAccNo() const
{
    return AccNo;
}
```

In fact, any time you have a function that does not or should not modify the object, you should declare it `const` out of general principles. This makes it easier for the compiler to trap mistakes for you and can save you a lot of debugging time.

## Problem 2:

```
vector<AccountHolder>::iterator searchAccount(const vector<AccountHolder>& v,long int accno)
```

returns a `vector<AccountHolder>::iterator`, but inside the method you are using and trying to return `vector<AccountHolder>::const_iterator`. These are different, and incompatible, types, so one of them has to be changed. I recommend

```
vector<AccountHolder>::const_iterator searchAccount(const vector<AccountHolder>& v,long int accno)
```

Because the `const_iterator` is unavoidable with a `const vector`.

Comment: can I use "long int getAccNo() const"(as you explain in method 1) with non-constant object.And one more doubt can I declare "long int getAccNo() const" as "const long int getAccNo()".